# Vuetify visibility class not working properly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Following the docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#visibility), I am trying to use a Vuetify visibility class to hide an element on small screens.

Using the following class produces the opposite of what I want removing the element on the larger screen size and adding it to the small one.

```
 <span class="d-sm-none d-md-flex">
   {{ username }}               
 </span>
```

I have tried changing the classes to this:

```
 <span class="d-md-none d-lg-flex">
  {{ username }}               
 </span>
```

However, this has the same effect - the element appears only on the small screen.

If anyone has any idea why these classes are not working as expected I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a default display, in your case it should be `d-none` instead of `d-sm-none`.

```
<span class="d-none d-md-flex">
    {{ username }}               
</span>
```

This element will be `hidden` on small screens and `flex` on medium screen devices.

Answer (score 0):

Set a the default display to `none`, and the other device screens to `block`.

```
<span class="d-none d-md-block">
    {{ username }}               
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample working code snippet/demo as per this [document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#visibility) and it's working fine.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <div class="d-none d-sm-flex">
        Not visible on x-small screens
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-flex">
        Not visible on x-small and small screens
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-flex">
        Not visible on x-small, small and medium screens
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```